# Java doens't recognise a comment field in an Excel sheet after using it with Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2010

I am creating an Excel sheet with Apache POI. In that sheet there is a cell with a comment. I can read that comment with Java and with Microsoft Excel.
If I open, change something and save the sheet with Microsoft Excel 2010, Java (Apache) doesn't recognize the comment field anymore. 
What's the problem and how could it be solved?

I create the comment like that:

```
        CreationHelper factory = wb.getCreationHelper();
        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        // When the comment box is visible, have it show in a 5x70 space
        ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
        anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+5);
        anchor.setRow1(row.getRowNum());
        anchor.setRow2(row.getRowNum()+70);


        Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
        String text = "";
        RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(text);

        comment.setString(str);
        row.createCell(0).setCellComment(comment);
```

And read with:

```
        row_slave.getCell(0).getCellComment().getString()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new cell. 
After saving the sheet with excel, Apache thinks that the comment field is null, because there is no other content (only the comment).
If I create a new cell (row_slave.createCell(0)) the comment is still there and is ready to be read.